# Electron how to focus browserwindow on receiving ipc message in a webview

Tags: webview, electron

I'm using electron with multiple browserWindows.
in this browserWindow I do have a webview where the content is shown.
Now I wat to send a new url to the webview of the other open browserWindow.

So I created a ipc listener in all of the browserwindows / webviews to update the url if a request is received. this is working fine so far.
Only what I can't get working is to focus/show the window with the new url.

I've tried to find a way to get the browserWindow instance for a webview, but that seems impossible...

How can I show/focus a window on receiving a message via IPC?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the instance of the current BrowserWindow pretty easy:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote    
const win = remote.getCurrentWindow()
```

Use `win.focus()` to bring that window the front.